# .Net Core 3 / Entity Framework Core putting connection string in Appsettings.json not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string

Still new to .NET Core but I'm trying to put my connection string in the `Appsettings.json` file. I'm following the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings) on how to do so and I think I have all my settings correct.

The project will compile and run, but when I hit the API I get an error

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

I used the connection string that EF Core put in my context and just commented it out so there is effectively nothing in the `DbContext`'s `OnConfiguring`. This is connecting to an Oracle database.

ModelContext.cs

```
public partial class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext()
    {
    }

    public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customer{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<HubToken> HubToken{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Token> Token { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        //{

        //    //optionsBuilder.UseOracle("user id=myusername;password=mypassword;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myserver)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=*****)))");
        //}
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Token>().HasNoKey();

        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:DefaultSchema", "MySCHEMA");
     }
```

Appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "user id=myusername;password=mypassword;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=servername)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)))"
  }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddControllersWithViews();

     services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options => {
                options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"));
     });
}
```

**UPDATE**

My code where the ModelContext is being called. I initially used the commented out "using" statement where I would just create the context. That's how I do it in .Net Framework but Core seems to be different. Then with some suggestions I tried the using statement trying to pass in the connection string in to the ModelContext but it doesn't like that either because the connection string is not available at that point. I've tried getting the connectionstring first before passing it to the ModelContext but something about that didn't work either, I just don't remember what it was since I've tried several things. I will say that at least at the moment it seems it was much simpler in EF for .Net. The DbContext would take care of getting the connection string from the app.config or web.config for me. Now it seems to be more of an effort to do that in Core but it's probably just because I'm so new withe the way Core works.

```
//using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext(configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")))
            {
                //Run the query and see if there are any results returned.
                var results = ctx.Token.FromSqlRaw(sbQuery.ToString()).ToList();

                if (results == null || results.Count == 0)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Api-Token not found in database. Access denied. Customer: {0} | Token: {1}", customer.ToString(), token.ToString());

                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Access Denied. Invalid Token");
                    return;
                }

                if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Model is in-valid.");
                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("Api-Token is valid.");
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Could you post your entire `ModelContext` class?

Comment: I added the ModelContext code in the post.

Comment: How about you comment out the `public ModelContext()` method? Keep `ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options)` only.

Comment: @Bemn I tried commenting that out but it needs it. Couldn't build without it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code so far. Please show the code/class, that uses the `ModelContext` class, including how it is getting the instance of the class, e.g. by using constructor dependency injection, or `GetService()` or `new ModelContext()`. It looks like you are not using the same instance of the `ModelContext` class that you have setup before with your `services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>()` call.

Comment: @Caverman hi. Did you manage to solve this issue? My God, Oracle is a nightmare.  There is huge lack of clear documentation, like with Mongo, for instance (MongoDb is better xxD). I am trying to reference my wallet into appsettings.json with no success. Did you ever try this ?

Comment: @aliosh I did get it to work and posted an answer in this thread. I'm personally a Microsoft fan and hate dealing with Oracle with a passion although it has honestly gotten better over the years. When I started this position 6 years ago Oracle was a complete nightmare to work with Entity Framework. I'm supposed to be leading my team to convert from Oracle on-prem to Azure SQL. Can't wait although I'm sure I'll have headaches along the way but in the long run it should be better.

Answer (score 3):

After more researching and playing around I finally got it to work. I'm posting my update so that it will hopefully help someone else down the road.

Added my connectionstring to the `appsettings.json` file

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "user id=myusername;password=mypassword;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=servername)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)))"
  }
```

Then add to the context info to the ConfigurationServices in the `Startup.cs` file. I believe this adds the information to the Dependency Injection container. I'm using Oracle but you just change to `options.UseSqlServer(connstring);` if needed. You can verify the correct connectionstring info by putting a break point to see it in debug mode.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //setting connstring separately here just to be able confirm correct value. 
            var connstring = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseOracle(connstring);
            });
        }
```

In your Controller/Class add the context to a page property and use the class constructor to get the DbContext from the DI container. Then use the `using` statement and reference the local property that has the connectionstring information.

```
    public class TokenAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
        {
        private readonly ModelContext _context;
                private readonly ILogger<TokenAuthorizationFilter> _logger;
                public TokenAuthorizationFilter(ILogger<TokenAuthorizationFilter> logger, ModelContext context)
                {
                    _logger = logger;
                    _context = context;
                }
                
                public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authorizing Api-Token.");
        
                    //Get the values from the Request Header
                    context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Api-Token", out var token);
                    context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Customer", out var customer);
        
                    var sbQuery = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sbQuery.Append("select * from YourUserTable ");
                    sbQuery.Append("where username=customer and password=token");
        
                    using (_context)
                    {
                        //Run the query and see if there are any results returned.
                        var results = _context.Token.FromSqlRaw(sbQuery.ToString()).ToList();
        
                        if (results == null || results.Count == 0)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation("Api-Token not found in database. Access denied. Customer: {0} | Token: {1}", customer.ToString(), token.ToString());
        
                            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Access Denied. Invalid Token");
                            return;
                        }
        
                        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation("Model is in-valid.");
                            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
                        }
        
                        _logger.LogInformation("Api-Token is valid.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetSection` method from `Configuration` class to get your connection string

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options => {
            options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DbConnection"]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I like this way of getting the ConnectionString and will probably keep it but it didn't fix the issue.